# Unable to attach or upload jpg/png files in SharePoint foundation 2010 list/Library

Tags: c#, sharepointfoundation2010

I can **not** attach a file to a list or library. Moreover, it is **impossible** to attach only pictures, files with extensions jpg, PNG, BMP (any image files). when i trying attach files to a list item or library item and press the save button element, nothing happens, and the list item form does not close. after a long wait nothing happened  If I try with other file extension, for example .docx,.xls,.wsp,csv,.pdf,.stp,.cs etc  - these file are uploaded without problems. These extensions not in Blocked File Types. And these problem on all sites and all web applications on the server.

Also I have checked it on by creating a brand new team site but NO luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my own issue!!

I have to update IE browser with latest windows update, previously it was IE 7 I have upgrade it to IE 9.

Now It taking all .jpeg and .Png images.